# Java date utility logic

Tags: java

I am writing the logic around the java Calender. I have following requirements.

- Working on day of week calender which contains 4 weeks in a month. Need to select Day of a week for a month. If selected week day is passed then for next month same week day has to be selected.
- If a month start on Saturday then seceond Monday will be 10th of that month rather than 3rd.

Please let me know if there are any utility is available in java to achieve above or any sample code will be much appreciated.

Comment: "If a month start on Saturday then seceond Monday will be 10th of that month rather than 3rd." Am I missing something here?

Comment: One word: Look into JODA.

Comment: That second requirement sounds less like a requirement and more like a statement by somebody who can count.  What's the actual issue here?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), the only good Date API for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`DateUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) class from Apache `commons-lang` library. It contains some useful methods for working with `Calendar` and `Date`.